# How to use not operator when using state variables in tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Let's say I have a h1 tag like this:

```html
<h1 data-position="left" class="data-[position=mid]:animate-fade-out">content</h1>
```

How can I use tailwind(maybe with some not operator based on my last search results but I still don't know how) to do `animate-fade-in` when `position` is not equal to `mid`?
There are three general choices on position attribute: `left`, `right` and `mid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for is `[&:not([data-position=mid])]` - every element which does not have `data-position="mid"` attribute. It is [arbitrary variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants) (`[&<CSS-selector>]`) which points to an element which does not (`:not()`) has `data-position` attribute with `mid` value (`[data-position=mid]`)

```html
<h1 data-position="left" class="[&:not([data-position=mid])]:animate-fade-out">content</h1>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Up2mBKVSnC)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```html
<h1 data-position="left" class="animate-fade-in data-[position=mid]:animate-fade-out">
  content
</h1>
```

Check out this [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/KhPoT3KYzy)

Comment: This isn't what I want, I want to have fade-in animation when position is not mid and have fade-out animation when position is mid.

Comment: Tried this one out before. Doesn't work either and the reason is that the animate-fade-out goes away but its effect stays long after fade-out is removed because we are applying fade-in once, it doesn't repeat again after fade-out is removed and the object stays hidden and invisible and the object doesn't do the fade-in animation.

Comment: @Mahmood can you please share a minimal reproducible code of the situation?

Answer (score 0):

The closest that I could get to was something like this:

```html
<h1 data-position="left" class="data-[position=mid]:animate-fade-out data-[position$=t]:animate-fade-in">content</h1>
```

Which `$=` is an attribute selector and works when the attribute data value ends with that letter 't' and I did that because there are three general choices on `position` attribute: `left`, `right` and `mid`
As it is obvious the `left` and `right` words end in `t` so I can enable and disable different animations based on that.

I'm sure there is a better way and if you know it, I'll be pretty happy to know that.